# Change contact name programmatically

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to change specific contact (by contactId) it's display name programmatically.
I've looked into similar q&a here and tried the following:

```
public static boolean updateContactName(Context context, long contactId, String newName) {
    try {
        ContentResolver contentResolver  = context.getContentResolver();

        ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
        ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=? AND " +
                                Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                        new String[]{Long.toString(contactId)})
                .withValue(CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, newName)
                .build());

        contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        CLog.d(ContactUtils.class, e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's working on some devices but in other (Such as LG G3) it's not working, Nothing is being update.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out :

```
try {
    String newName = txtName.getText();
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> cpoList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    cpoList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=? AND " +
           Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", new String[]{contact_id})
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, newName)
    .build());
    ContentProviderResult[] result = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, cpoList);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Do Any thing
}
```

Comment: Did you check the Error Log ?

Comment: Yes. nothing. ContentProviderResult[] result length is 1 but inside count is 0

Comment: Did you checked your contacts ? all contacts ? sim contacts ? device contacts ?

Comment: Checked everything. same code. works on devices such as nexus 5x but not in lg g3